# Transform rows with common key to single row with multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes to merge into one. The `main_id` frame contains lists of unique ids. The `ref_data` frame contains some data about the objects in `main_id`. Some of the ids are referenced twice, some only once, so I think I need a one-to-many join. I want to capture both the `period` value and its corresponding `quantity`, with some identifying suffix linking the two. I've reviewed the pandas documentation on merge but didn't really see something mentioning this use case. Any help gratefully received.

**Example**

main_id frame:

```
main_id = pd.DataFrame(data = [123,456,789], columns=['id'])

main_id

Out[109]: 
    id
0  123
1  456
2  789
```

ref_data frame:

```
ref_data = pd.DataFrame()
ref_data['main_id'] = main_id['id'].append(main_id['id'].loc[1:])
ref_data = ref_data.reset_index(drop=True)
ref_data['period'] = ['24hr', 'Day', 'Day', 'Night', 'Night']
ref_data['quantity'] = [3,4,6,5,2]
ref_data

Out[111]: 
   main_id period  quantity
0      123   24hr         3
1      456    Day         4
2      789    Day         6
3      456  Night         5
4      789  Night         2
```

Desired output:

```
Out[112]: 
    id period_1_ref  period_1_val period_2_ref  period_2_val
0  123         24hr             3          NaN           NaN
1  456          Day             4        Night           5.0
2  789          Day             6        Night           2.0
```

Comment: Is there ever > 2 occurrences of `main_id` in `ref_data`

Comment: No, there should only ever be one (in which case `period` will be '24hr') or two (`period` will be Day and Night in any order)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you, just use `groupby` no need to merge

```
mrg = ref_data.groupby('main_id').apply(lambda x: x[['period','quantity']].values.ravel())

pd.DataFrame(mrg.tolist(),index=mrg.index,columns=['period_1_ref','period_1_val','period_2_ref','period_2_val'])

       period_1_ref  period_1_val period_2_ref  period_2_val
main_id                                                      
123             24hr             3         None           NaN
456              Day             4        Night           5.0
789              Day             6        Night           2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

A similar approach using groupby:

```
(
    ref_data.set_index('main_id').groupby(level=0)
    .apply(lambda x: x.values.reshape(1,-1)[0])
    .apply(pd.Series)
    .set_axis(['period_1_ref','period_1_val','period_2_ref', 'period_2_val'],
              axis=1, inplace=False)
)

Out[117]: 
        period_1_ref  period_1_val period_2_ref  period_2_val
main_id                                                      
123             24hr             3          NaN           NaN
456              Day             4        Night           5.0
789              Day             6        Night           2.0
```